# How do i resolve "bad operand types for binary operator '+' " error

Tags: java, generics

Just started to learn the concept of Generics. Still not clear though. The code I wrote is just adding 2 number(Integer). And it's showing - "bad operand types for binary operator '+' ". Can anyone help me to understand the error? How do i resolve it?

```
package Generics;

public class Class <T> {

    public T a;
    public T b;
    public T z;

    public T add(T a,T b){

        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;   

        z = a + b;

        return z;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Class <Integer> obj1 = new Class <> ();


        Integer result = obj1.add(5,6 );

        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - bad operand types for binary operator '+'
  first type:  T
  second type: T
    at Generics.Class.add(Class.java:14)
    at Generics.Class.main(Class.java:26)
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: The `+` Operator cannot be used on any random Object class which your Generic parameter T represents. Think what would happen if someone would create a `Class<List<?>>`. Also: It is a **really** bad idea to name your class `Class`

Comment: how should i proceed then

Comment: Do you really want this method to work for *any* type? Or do you have numbers in mind?

Comment: @LutzHorn for now just integer

Comment: If you only want to use `Integer`, there is no reason to use generics. If you want to execute any method on the passed `T` instances, this type will have the method you want ot execute. So narrow `T` to an interface: `<T implements InterfaceWithMethod>`.

Answer (score 2):

First : don't use `Class` as classname ! That is misleading.

Here `T` has as base type : `Object`.
Objects cannot be summed with a `+` operator or any arithmetical operator.
You can only do that with primitive or String (from any side for `String`s).
The problem is that generics are typed with objects not with primitives.
So you can only use as upperbounded wildcard : `T extends Number`.
But there still, you cannot sum `Number`s as `Number` are objects. 
So you should get their primitive values (int, double, etc...) to achieve that.

While convoluted and with several unchecked casts, you could write something :

```
public class Computation<T extends Number> {

    private static Map<Class<? extends Number>, BinaryOperator<Number>> map = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        map.put(Integer.class, (a, b) -> Integer.valueOf(a.intValue() + b.intValue()));
        map.put(Double.class, (a, b) -> Double.valueOf(a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue()));
        // and so for
    }

    private final Class<T> runtimeType;

    public Computation(Class<T> runtimeType) {
        this.runtimeType = runtimeType;
    }    

    T add(T a, T b) {
        return (T) map.get(runtimeType)
                      .apply(a, b);
        // handle the not found value in the map case too        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Computation<Integer> obj1 = new Computation<>(Integer.class);
        Integer result = obj1.add(5, 6);
        System.out.println(result);

        Computation<Double> obj2 = new Computation<>(Double.class);
        Double result2 = obj2.add(5.5, 6.4);
        System.out.println(result2);    
    }
}
```

Output :

> 11
>
> 11.9

But a neater solution (no unchecked cast, no map to handle and so for...), would be probably to introduce an interface `Computation` and to define implementations for each numeric type to handle :

```
public interface Computation<T extends Number> {
    T add(T a, T b);
}
public class IntegerComputation implements  Computation<Integer>{
    @Override
    public Integer add(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a.intValue() + b.intValue();
    }
}
public class DoubleComputation implements Computation<Double> {
    @Override
    public Double add(Double a, Double b) {
        return a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: according to This - I am declaring z as "double" type first, but in the "add" method the return type is "T" . While the method is returning "z" aren't they suppose to conflict?

Comment: That doesn't match indeed. So you are constraint to perform some uncheck casts to make it  compile.